# Click only one row of ListView at a single time in Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a ListView in my application.
Below is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
 ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] wrongOrder = new String[] {"Am/I/Girl/Good","Ila/Is/Name/My","Barking/Dog/Is"};
    String[] rightOrder = new String[]{"I/Am/Good/Girl","My/Name/Is/Ila","Dog/Is/Barking"};

     DashboardListAdapter codeLearnArrayAdapter = new DashboardListAdapter(this,0, wrongOrder,rightOrder);// new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, codeLearnChapters);

      listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     listView.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);
  }
}
```

In my adapter class I created two LinearLayout,in one layout there are four buttons with random data "Am","I","Good","Girl" which I pass from Main Activity and another layout just below the above layout with same number of buttons,and put those layout in parent Relative layout for drawing single row. Now when I double tap on above layout button then the data compare with rightOrder String[] which I pass from MainActivity to Adapter and take the suitable position. Everything working fine,but my task is at first time one first row's buttons are clickable,other rows are not focused,and when I perform the first row task then second row's buttons focused and first and other rows not get focused. My adapter class is

```
public class DashboardListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Button clickedBtn;
private int mLayout;
private Activity mContext;
private String[] listArray;
String[] rightArray;

Button[][] btnArray;
int[] indexArray;
private int mLastPosition = -1;

static int id = 1000;
static int id1 = 5000;
LinearLayout innerLayout2;
LinearLayout innerLayout1;

static int innerLayoutTag = 778;
static boolean flag = false;



public DashboardListAdapter(Activity context, int resource,
        String[] lsitArray,String[] rightArray) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.listArray = lsitArray;
    this.rightArray = rightArray;
    this.btnArray = new Button[listArray.length][];
    this.indexArray = new int[listArray.length];


    this.setLayout(resource);
}


@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return listArray.length;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

/**
 * @return the layout
 */
public int getLayout() 
{
    return mLayout;
}

/**
 * @param layout
 *            the layout to set
 */
public void setLayout(int layout) 
{
    this.mLayout = layout;
}

/**
 * @return the context
 */
public Activity getContext() 
{
    return mContext;
}

/**
 * @param context
 *            the context to set
 */
public void setContext(Activity context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mContext);              
        String content = null;
        content = listArray[position];
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(content.split("/")));

        innerLayout1 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        innerLayout1.setId(100);
        innerLayout2 = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        Button[] rowBtnArray = new Button[list.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Button   btn = new Button(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btn.setLayoutParams(p);
            btn.setText(list.get(i));
            btn.setId(id++);
            btn.setTag(i);
            innerLayout1.addView(btn);
            innerLayout1.setTag(position);
            Button btnNew = new Button(mContext);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btnNew.setLayoutParams(p1);
            btnNew.setText("hello");
            btnNew.setId(id1++);
            innerLayout2.addView(btnNew);
            rowBtnArray[i] = btnNew;
            btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(mContext));
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
                    clickedBtn = (Button)v;

                    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                }
            });


        }

        btnArray[position] = rowBtnArray;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,innerLayout1.getId());
        innerLayout2.setLayoutParams(p1);
        innerLayout2.setTag(innerLayoutTag);
        layout.addView(innerLayout1);

        layout.addView(innerLayout2);

        convertView = layout; //INSTEAD OF INFLATING A LAYOUT FOR THE ROW I JUST BINDED IT TO THE RECENTLY CREATED LAYOUT 
    } 
    else 
    {

    }
    return convertView;

}

public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public Context context;
    public String phno;

    public MyGestureDetector(Context con)
    {
        this.context=con;       
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("in Double tap");
        String str = (String) clickedBtn.getText();
        LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout)clickedBtn.getParent();
        int rowNum = (int) rowLayout.getTag();
        String content = rightArray[rowNum];
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(content.split("/")));
        Button[]  rowBtn = btnArray[rowNum];

        for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++)
        {
            String text = list.get(j);
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
            {
                int index = indexArray[rowNum];
                if(index == j)
                {
                    Button btn = rowBtn[j];
                    btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn.setText(str);
                    index+=1;
                    indexArray[rowNum] = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) mContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(400);
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

  }
 }
```

I created the layout programmatically without inflate.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is unclear but guessing from the question, do you want to set the choice mode for the `ListView`? If you want the user to only select one item at a time, you can do this as follows:

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

You can then get the position of the selected item as follows:

```
list.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

**Update:**

Override the `isEnabled (int position)` method of your adapter. Keep a track of which position is enabled. Any other positions will result in this method returning false.

Comment: Actually I want that when I start the application, then first row is clickable and other rows are disable and when I perform complete operation with first row then control pass to second row and first row and remaining rows are disable except second. If you can post the code also,it will be great help.

Comment: I already do this but I am not getting the right result. Please post the implementation as well. Thanks. And one more thing when I perform first row task then second row will enable, then how isEnabled method used.